# In Indesign, is it possible to put a title into greps of a paragraph style?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, grep

In Indesign, is it possible to put a name or description into greps of a paragraph style to remember instantly what was the purpose of it?

I mean any query ever designed for it, or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add comment inside the (?#) modifier.

\d+(?=.)(?#Number one or more before a dot)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a text after a vertical line at the end of the GREP, like:

```
\d+(?=\.)|change_number_size_followed_by_dot
```

This works always that your text doesn't include the exact word_phrase
*change_number_size_followed_by_dot*

Comment: Aaahhaa!... otherwise it works as "Or" function, is it true?

Comment: Yes, but adding a_phrase_like_this_it_would_have_to_be_a_big_coincidence to change the text with the GREP 

Comment: great trick! thank you a lot. also I think adding it at very begining of grep won't budge an is easier to look at what we call "description"! ever tried it!

Comment: Hey Dan, @Jean-Claude Tremblay added a new code as "Comment Modifier" which is design for this tread's purpose. Take a look at that here. sorry but I changed correct answer! please forgive me!! :D - ;)